# php loop inside different loop how?

Tags: php, html

sorry for my english
i want echo limit element inside each div
here is my code:

```
<?php 
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
echo "<div class='container'>";
for ($j=1;$j<=8;$j++) {
  echo "content Number" . $j . "<br>";
}    
echo "</div>"
}
?>
```

my code doesn't work like i wish and i want result like this

```
<div class="container">
content Number 1
content Number 2
</div>
<div class="container">
content Number 3
content Number 4
</div>
<div class="container">
content Number 5
content Number 6
</div>
<div class="container">
content Number 7
content Number 8
</div>
```

Comment: You may be able to [use a counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031929/924299) to determine when to start a new div or [use `array_chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151287/924299) to split the array into groups of two.

Comment: I just answered the same thing, seconds apart.

Comment: very thanks my brothers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use the `array_chunk` method to explode an array into suitable pieces for display using simple `foreach` loops.

```
$max=4;
$bits=array_chunk( range( 1, ( $max * 2 ) ), 2 );

foreach( $bits as $pair ){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    foreach( $pair as $i )echo 'content Number '.$i.'<br />';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
    echo "<div class='container'>";
    for ($j=1;$j<=2;$j++) {
        echo "content Number" . $counter . "<br>";
        $counter++;
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

You were starting to count from 1 every time you started another `.container` div. You want one counter (`$counter`) instead. Then, loop once for the amount of containers, then again for the amount of content in each container!

Comment: Your output doesn't match what the OP is requesting.

Comment: Fixed, just put the div echos in the wrong place. My mistake

Comment: yeah you are right this my mistake thanks